# PowerShell get the same Read-Host if wrong input

Tags: powershell

I'm struggling with to get the same Read-Host if the user put in an invalid input.
I have tried many different solution but can't get it to work.

My example is a simple yes/no script. But I want it to give me the Read-Host again if it's not ja/nej. I'ts also okay to get a more universal solution, like if wrong input tray again kind of way.

```
Write-Host "Er du født før 1. januar 2000?";
$Readhost = Read-Host "ja/nej"
switch ($Readhost)
{
ja {write-host "Så er du over 18 år gammel"}
nej {write-host "Så er du yngere end 18 år"}
default {write-host ”Svar på spørgsmålet!”}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a `while` loop!

```
Write-Host "Er du født før 1. januar 2000?";
$Readhost = ""

while ($Readhost -notin "ja", "nej") {
    $Readhost = Read-Host "ja/nej"

    switch($Readhost) {
        ja {write-host "Så er du over 18 år gammel"}
        nej {write-host "Så er du yngere end 18 år"}
    } 
}
```

Comment: I'd keep the default to inform the user why asking again.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a pre-defined set of options like "yes/no", then consider using a menu to avoid invalid input.  For example:

```
$selectedFruit = $host.UI.PromptForChoice('Select a Fruit', "Which fruit is your favorite?", ('&Apple', '&Melon', 'Man&go','&Quit'), 0)

switch($selectedFruit)
{
    0 {Write-Host "You chose 'Apple'"}
    1 {Write-Host "You chose 'Melon'"}
    2 {Write-Host "You chose 'Mango'"}
}
```

In the console, this produces a menu like this:

[image]

As you can see it will continue to prompt the user if they enter an incorrect value (or select the `Quit` option).  If you don't want a default value, change the `0` in `PromptForChoice` to `-1`.