# PowerShell only accept Int

Tags: powershell

I am scripting some code that will help my team automate some AD User mod tasks and ensure we are doing things consistently.  I am prompting for a users last name (or partial last name) and return a list of matching users (Index, Name, userID) to ensure we mod the correct account.  For example if I search for Smith it would return:

```
[0] Smith, John   jsmith
[1] Smith, Jane   jsmith1
[2] Smithfield, Robert  rsmithfield
```

The tech would then need to enter the corresponding number of the account they want to modify.  I put in an input validation check to ensure that a valid index number is chosen (in this case it will not accept a negative int or an int grater than 2).  Unfortunately I do not know how to also ensure that a letter or symbol is not is entered.  In this case if a users enters the number 3 it will return a message of "Invalid Selection" but if they enter the letter d, it accepts it and then errors out.  How do I make it so it will onluy accept an int?  FYI - after I get this working I will be creating functions and function calls so it is more modular, this is just initial testing of the concept.

```
#prompt for last name (or at least portion of last name, then conver to a string with wild card for use in filter
$lname = Read-Host "`nEnter at least the first three chars of users last name (you may enter full last name)"
$search = $lname + "*"

#Empty arrays
$ResultsArray=@("")
$ADUsersList=@("")

#add aduser properties to array, return error and exit if no user found
$ADUsersList += Get-ADUser -filter 'surname -like $search' -Properties * | select name,samaccountname,DistinguishedName
if ($ADUsersList.count -le 1){
    Write-host "USER NOT FOUND"
    return
}

#populate a 2D array with NAM and with UserID
$ResultsArray = @(($ADUsersList.name),($ADUsersList.samaccountname))

#return list of found users and user ids. Preface with index number to use for selection menu
for($i=0;$i-le $ResultsArray[0].length-1;$i++){
    “[{0}] = {1} `t {2}” -f $i,$ResultsArray[0][$i],$ResultsArray[1][$i]
}

#Prompt 
[int]$selection = Read-Host "`nEnter number for user you want to modify"

#Input validation - Only allow a valid index #.  If valid, write user selected to screen before proceeding 
if ($selection -gt $ResultsArray[0].length -or $selection -lt 0){
    Write-host "INVALID SELECTION!!!" -ForegroundColor Red
} 
else {
    Write-Host "`nYou selected user " -nonewline 
    Write-Host $ResultsArray[0][$selection] -nonewline -ForegroundColor Green
    Write-Host " with user ID a of " -nonewline 
    Write-Host $ResultsArray[1][$selection] -nonewline -ForegroundColor Green
}
```

Comment: Try using a more formal PowerShell prompt, as shown in this example: [PowerShell get the same Read-Host if wrong input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53223272/powershell-get-the-same-read-host-if-wrong-input/53223728#53223728)

Comment: A couple of inconsequential asides: Technically, `$ResultsArray` is a _jagged_ array, not a 2D array. Also, you don't need to initialize your arrays separately; e.g., `$ADUsersList = Get-ADUser ...` will do (or, if you want to ensure that the result is an array even in the event that only _one_ user is returned: `$ADUsersList = @(Get-ADUser ...)`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be an easier way to do it, you can use the [`-as` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_type_operators?view=powershell-7.2#-as-operator) for safe conversion and a regex pattern to ensure that the input was a numeric digit:

```bash
$testCollection = 0..(Get-Random -Maximum 10)
for ($i = 0; $i -le $testCollection.Count - 1; $i++) {
    '[{0}] = {1}' -f $i, $testCollection[$i]
}
$selection = (Read-Host "`nEnter number for user you want to modify") -as [int]

if ($selection -notmatch '^[0-9]+$' -or $selection -ge $testCollection.Count) {
    return Write-Warning 'Invalid stuff..'
}
$testCollection[$selection]
```

But even simpler and more robust would be to use [`Out-GridView -PassThru`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-gridview?view=powershell-7.3):

```bash
$selection = Get-ADUser -Filter "surname -like '$search'" |
    Select-Object name, samaccountname, DistinguishedName |
    Out-GridView -PassThru -Title 'Choose a user'

if (-not $selection) {
    return 'Nothing was selected...'
}

Write-Host "`nYou selected user " -NoNewline 
Write-Host $selection.Name -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Green
Write-Host ' with user ID a of ' -NoNewline 
Write-Host $selection.samAccountName -NoNewline -ForegroundColor Green
```

Comment: @n0rd `int32` has negative numbers too. it wouldnt make sense if I was using `uint32` but im not, I decided to remove the cast to `uint32` to not confuse OP.

Comment: Are you seriously checking for negative numbers with regex?.. Also `-as` will not return `$null` for failed conversions, it will return 0, which might lead to unexpected results.

Comment: `'a string' -as [int]` is `$null` not `0` isn't it? @n0rd the current code as is will not produce unexpected results, the regex is ensuring that, maybe you should try it yourself.

Comment: Indeed re `$null`; I missed that due to use of `[int]` with `-as` (rather than `[Uint32]`) , `$selection` does receive negative numbers as such, so the `-notmatch` operation _is_ successful in weeding out negative numbers. An alternative is to stay in the realm of numbers (relying on `$null -lt 1` being `$true`): `$selection -lt 1 -or $selection -ge $testCollection.Count`. /cc @n0rd

Answer (score 0):

[`OutGridView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-gridview)  `-PassThru`, as suggested in [Santiago's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77441668/45375), is an elegant solution that *bypasses* your validation problem.

However, it involves pop-up of a *GUI*, which may not be desired.

An alternative way to handle this in the *console* (terminal) is to **test the user input for being contained in the array of valid indices, using the [`-in` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-in-and--notin)**.

A simplified example:

```bash
if (($num = Read-Host 'Enter a number between 1 and 3') -in (1..3)) {
  # Now it's safe to convert the string input to [int]
  $num = [int] $num 
  "You chose index $num."
} else {
  Write-Warning "'$num' is not a number between 1 and 3"
}
```

Spelled out in the context of (a simplified version of) your code:

```bash
# Sample jagged results array.
$ResultsArray = ('foo', 'bar', 'baz'), ('...')

# Get the list of valid (1-based) indices.
$validIndices = 1..$ResultsArray[0].Count

# ... print the index-prefixed list of results.

# Keep prompting until the user's input is valid index.
while ($true) {
  $userInput = Read-Host "`nEnter number for user you want to modify"
  if ($userInput -in $validIndices) {
     $selectedIndex = [int] $userInput
     break
  } else {
     Write-Warning "'$userInput' is not a number between 1 and $($validIndices.Count). Please try again."
  }
}

# Getting here means that a valid choice was made.
Write-Host "Selected index: $selectedIndex"
# ...
```

Note:

- Even though [`Read-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/read-host)'s output is invariably a *string*, whereas the elements of the array stored in `$validIndices` are of type `[int]`, use of the [`-in` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-in-and--notin) still works as expected (the same applies analogously to the operands-reversed [`-contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-contains-and--notcontains) operator):

  - PowerShell tries to convert the LHS operand to each RHS element's data type, if necessary:

    - If the conversion *fails*, the comparison is (quietly) considered to be `$false`
    - If the conversion *succeeds*, the comparison is performed based on the conversion result.
    - (Either way, an element-individual comparison yielding `$true` short-circuits the operation and returns `$true`; otherwise, element-by-element comparison continues.)
  - Note that the above implies that string input such as `'0x2'` and `'+2'` would match an `[int]` array element of value `2` as well.
    Surrounding whitespace is always ignored (e.g, `'  2  '` matches a `2` element too).